# Differential equations with conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's say I am given a inhomogeneous differential equation of second grade with 2 conditions.

I can receive my solution by adding the solution of the homogeneous part and one solution of the inhomogeneous part. I also know that, if the 2 conditions are independent, my free parameters are uniquely determined by these conditions.

Now my question is, do the solutions for the homogeneous and inhomogeneous part already have to fulfill my conditions?

I hope you understand my question, if not, please comment